# Accessing Java bean properties from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have wsimport-ed Java classes with standard bean conventions:

```
public class Request {
    protected String vin;

    public String getVin() {
        return vin;
    }

    public void setVin(String value) {
        this.vin = value;
    }
}
```

I expected to use this class in Kotlin using nice property syntax:

```
override fun search(request: Request): Response {
  log.info("search(vin={})", request.vin);
  ...
```

but this code does not compile:

```
Error:(59, 64) Kotlin: Cannot access 'vin': it is 'protected/*protected and package*/' in 'SmvSearchRequest'
```

`request.getVin()` works, of course, but that doesn't look better than Java. Is there some way to treat those classes as property holders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was missing pre-M13, it is now fixed in M13, see [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-400)

Comment: It's not really a bug. It's just a feature that was only recently implemented.

Comment: UPDATE:  The referenced issue (KT-400) has been resolved, and the code in the question should now function as expected.  Can you please update the answer.